# Are frozen pizzas countable or uncountable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

As you know pizzas are countable But when you add another word like, frozen, does it remain countable?

Generally, when you add an adjective to a countable word are there any changes?

Comment: I think that's rather informal to use it as countable

Comment: "Frozen pizza" is countable. I can't think of any examples where adding an adjective changes the countability of a word.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, There is not exact expression. There is just a question which wants the student to match two words in the table.For example jam with a jar or bread with a loaf finally frozen pizzas with one pepperoni and one simple. Bye the way thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks, moreroz, for clearing that matter up. So, why do you think frozen pizzas are uncountable compared to ordinary pizzas? Is there anything in the book, or something your teacher told you, which confuses you? (The answer is countable: I want to buy a/one frozen pizza / I want to buy three frozen pizzas. You don't normally ask for "some frozen pizza.)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, I check the dictionary and I saw pizza can be both countable and non countable, and I confused but Noah who write the difference. It is so nice to see there are a lot of good people try to solve my question. I can not believe it thanks again.

Comment: Changed the question to not quote

Comment: @moreroz So glad to have helped you! Everyone at ELU does their best to give a hand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can buy **a frozen pizza** from a supermarket. (countable)

If you have friends coming over for dinner then you might purchase *three* different types of pizzas.

1. Napoli (anchovies and capers)
2. Margherita (cheese and tomato)
3. Quattro stagioni (four seasons)

So now you have **three frozen pizzas** to take back home and cook in the oven.

Once your friends arrive, and they are sitting at the table. You could ask:

- Would you like **some** "Napoli" or **some** "Margherita"? (here, pizza is uncountable. You are not offering a whole pizza.)
- Which **pizza** would you prefer? (countable, because the person can choose one pizza)
- Which **slice** would you like? ( *a slice of* pizza is countable. You can have *two or more slices* depending on your hunger.)

Answer (score 4):

Pizza is both countable and uncountable. If you are talking about the food then it's uncountable as in *I ordered pizza for dinner.* You could very well say that you ate a pizza or ordered a pizza(meaning one pizza). But when you are talking about the kind of pizza in general, it's uncountable. For example, *I like oven pizza.* However, you could very well say, *I had an oven cooked pizza.*

Comment: -1 As @Mari-LouA has shown, 'kinds' of pizzas are also often countable: "In the freezer, I've currently got two Thin & crispy Vegetable pizzas."

Comment: @TrevorD Not in the example I provided.

Comment: I wasn't discussing your *example*. You wrote "when it comes to which kind, it's usually uncountable", and I disagree with the generality of that statement.

Comment: @TrevorD Fixed that part.