# Using "pizza" as countable vs. uncountable

Tags: word-choice, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> I ate pizzas on Sundays.
>   I ate pizza on Sundays.

*Pizza* is both uncountable and countable. In these sentences, is there any difference in meaning? Is one of them wrong?

Comment: related [Are frozen pizzas countable or uncountable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121767/are-frozen-pizzas-countable-or-uncountable)

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, this question can be best answered by the answer to [this question about recipes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199473/countable-ingredient-pluralization-for-english-cookbooks). For the lazy, it basically states that if you're referring to an amount of food that is less than a whole instance of that type of food, you use the uncountable; otherwise use the countable. So unless you ate multiple pizzas, the second example is correct.